# How to convert post_save to pre_save signals?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have setup a OtoO relationship between Property and a ListingDetail Model:

```
class Property(models.Model):
   .
   .
   .
    def __str__(self):
        return "Property " + str(self.pk)
```

ListingDetail Model:

```
class ListingDetial(models.Model):
    property = models.OneToOneField("properties.Property", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   .
   .
   .
```

Now I donot want to manually select the **property** field in LocationDetail Model and instead want to save it automatically.

Currently I have used the post_save signal to achieve the funtionality:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Property)
def ensure_sub_section_model_exists(sender, **kwargs):

    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        ListingDetial.objects.get_or_create(property=kwargs.get('instance'))
```

But the issue with this approach is that every time a Property instance is created it creates a ListingDetail, the only trouble with this approach is that I need to keep all the field nullable.
What I want is that after I create the ListingModel, the **property** stores the value same as PK of ListingModel.

Answer (score 0):

If you first create `Property` and then add `ListingDetail` to it, it would be better to have that OneToOneField in your `Property` model. And there is no need for signals to do this.

```py
class Property(models.Model):
    listing_detail = models.OneToOneField("properties.ListingDetail", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.listing_detail = ListingDetail.objects.create()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This field is required., that is what it says in Django admin

Comment: Also isn't that anything no different from above code, where a instance of other models  are created but field will still have to stay null or blank in order to successfully create a model.

Comment: You can set required to false in that field. And by your save method, you are sure that for every Property, a listing_detail will be created